# How to get all the nodes with the anchor name of a scene

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit

I know how to create an anchor with given name and adds it to the scene but I am confused about how to retrieve them after the creation.

First I create the anchors in the group number that I want (`groupNumber0`, `groupNumber1`, etc):

```
let strokeAnchor = StrokeAnchor(name: "strokeAnchor\(groupNumber/2)", transform: float4x4(float4(1, 0, 0, 0),
                                                                                              float4(0, 1, 0, 0),
                                                                                              float4(0, 0, 1, 0),
                                                                                              float4(touchPositionInFrontOfCamera.x,
                                                                                                     touchPositionInFrontOfCamera.y,
                                                                                                     touchPositionInFrontOfCamera.z,
                                                                                                     1)))
self.sceneView.session.add(anchor: strokeAnchor)
```

I am confused that the session add method just adds the anchor, does it adds the name property as well? However when I try to retrieve the relevant nodes, the result node is just `nil`.

```
let parentNode = sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "strokeAnchor0", recursively: true)
print(parentNode)
```

Does this mean the name of anchor is different from the name of the resulting node? How do I select all the nodes that have the name `groupNumber0` in this case?

Comment: I have double checked, the names will be "strokeAnchor0", not "strokeAnchor0.0" because I have downcast it to int

Comment: I have confirmed using sceneView.session.currentFrame?.anchors that the anchors are been added correctly with the current name. I just need a way to retrieve the nodes back from the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question using (sceneView.anchor(for:node)?.name)! to get the name of the anchor of the associated node. I think the reverse will work too (get the node with given anchor).